# Python, Source-Code Encoding Problem

Tags: python, character-encoding

I'm using Notepad++ editor on windows with format set to ASCII,
I've read  "PEP 263: Source Code Encodings" and amended my code accordingly (I think), but there are characters still printing in hex...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import os, sys

a_munge = [ "A", "4", "/\\", "\@", "/-\\", "^", "aye", "?" ]
b_munge = [ "B", "8", "13", "I3", "|3" , "P>", "|:", "!3", "(3", "/3", "3","]3" ]
c_munge = [ "C", "<", "(", "{", "(c)" ]
d_munge = [ "D", "|)", "|o", "?", "])", "[)", "I>", "|>", " ?", "T)", "0", "cl" ]
e_munge = [ "E", "3", "&", "€", "£", "[-", "|=-", "?" ]
         .
         .
         .
```

Comment: so, did you try actually changing Notepad++'s file format to UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should be using unicode literals (e.g. `u'€'`) instead.

Comment: Well I just tryed that and I got  
 
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\python\passgen.py", line 9
    e_replace_list = [ "E", "3", "&", u"Ç", "ú", "[-", "|=-", "?" ]
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in positio
unexpected code byte

Comment: 1) Your file isn't UTF-8. 2) They should *all* be unicode literals. http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: ...informative presentation thanks, although I'm not sure Im much wiser... To clarify what you said, 'They should all be unicode literals' when u say 'all' do you mean all characters not included in the ASCII set? Ive done this any it runs, but non ASCII characters are still printed in unicode hex eg. € = u'\u20ac'

Comment: Then you should consider showing the code that actually does the work.

Comment: <code> print e_munge </code>

This is the way Im doing it at the moment just for debugging purposes but eventually the characters will printed to a Tkinter GUI

Comment: That doesn't print the characters, that prints the `repr()` of the list. Things will not work as you like. Print the actual elements if you want it to work.

Comment: Ok got it now thanks for all your help. Im new to python (not programming though) and I guess throwing character encoding in the mix doesn't help... Thanks again,

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

declares that the **source file** is saved in UTF-8.  Anything else is an error.

When you declare **byte strings** in your source code:

```
e_munge = [ "E", "3", "&", "€", "£", "[-", "|=-", "?" ]
```

then byte strings like **"€"** will actually contain the encoded bytes used to save the source file.

When you use Unicode strings instead:

```
    e_munge = [ u"E", u"3", u"&", u"€", u"£", u"[-", u"|=-", u"?" ]
```

then when **u** followed by the byte-string **"€"** is read by Python from a source file, it uses the declared encoding to decode that character into Unicode.

An illustration:

```
# coding: utf-8
bs = '€'
us = u'€'
print repr(bs)
print repr(us)
```

OUTPUT:

```
'\xe2\x82\xac'
u'\u20ac'
```

Comment: ok I already deduced that, but how do I get it to print out the character € and not the unicode code...

Answer (score 1):

`print some_list` is in effect `print repr(some_list)` -- that's why you see `\u20ac` instead of a Euro character. For debugging purposes, the "unicode hex" is exactly what you need for unambiguous display of your data.

You appear to have perfectly OK unicode objects in your list; I suggest that you don't "print" the list to Tkinter.

Comment: Well I won't be printing all the lists to Tkinter(atleast not at one time). The program will be a simple password generator which will allow a user to input a word that they would like to use for a password, the program will then do a pseudo-random munge of the word and output the result to a tkinter text box so that the user can copy and past to wherever... .Why do suggest that I dont output to Tkinter?

Comment: You said that "the characters will printed to a Tkinter GUI". I'm merely suggesting that you don't use the Python `print` statement to send the data to Tkinter for display.

Comment: Ok fair enough, I guess my previous comment was a little ambiguous, thanks for your input.